# forkしたSphinxをローカルのclone環境でpytestを実行すると「ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_testcapi'」が発生

Tags: python3, sphinx, circleci

Sphinxの開発環境に慣れている方ならFAQかもしれません。
宜しくお願いします。

#### 質問

forkしたSphinxをローカルのclone環境でpytestを実行する場合に、必要な準備について教えてください。

#### 現状

次のエラーが発生します。（「=」「_」「！」は多いので削りました）

```
======== ERRORS ==============================================
________ ERROR collecting tests/test_util_inspect.py ____________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/naomasa/sphinx/devcore/tests/test_util_inspect.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_util_inspect.py:19: in <module>
    import _testcapi
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_testcapi'
======== short test summary info ======================================
ERROR tests/test_util_inspect.py
!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
======== 1 error in 6.40s =========================================
```

#### 環境

- windows10/cygwin64
- python3.8.10
- Sphinx4.2.0/時々4.3.0+(cloneからsdistして直接pip installしたもの)

#### 確認したこと

- circleci上ではエラーは発生しないでテストが終わります。
- 「ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_testcapi'」から分かった次のことは試しました。

  - `pip install python-test` … インストール済み
  - `python -m pytest tests` … 同じエラー
  - `pip install -e .` and `python -m pytest tests` … 同じエラー
  - 同じ環境で `make test` … 同じエラー
  - 同じ環境で `python setup.py test` … setuptoolsのエラー。

#### 考察

次の可能性を考えています。

- インポートしていないパッケージがある。
- 実行時に設定しておく環境変数がある。
- その他、何らかの設定が必要。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python本体のテスト用パッケージが不足している可能性があります。
CircleCIでテスト実行に使用している環境はこちらです。
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/docker-ci/blob/master/Dockerfile

Ubuntuであれば `apt install python3-dev` のインストールで解消する可能性がありそうです。

Comment: いただいた情報のおかげで解決しました。詳細は自己回答に載せておきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

いただいた回答がきっかけで解決しました。
回答として情報を追記しておきます。

#### 結論

cygwinのパッケージが不足していた

- cygwinパッケージ `python38-test` のイントールで解決。
- `pip install python-test` はしていたので意識外でした。

現状FAILが一つありますが、エラーではなくFAILなので追々調べます。
（「=」は削っています）

```
…
-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
==== short test summary info ======================================
FAILED tests/test_ext_imgconverter.py::test_ext_imgconverter - sphinx.errors.ExtensionError: conv...
==== 1 failed, 1735 passed, 28 skipped, 9 warnings in 611.24s (0:10:11) =======
```

#### 解決まで

1. 回答をもらう。
2. もらった情報から、確かに「python3-dev」辺りが怪しいと思う。
3. cygwinで該当しそうなものを確認する。
4. ここで「cygwinで検索」を思いつく。
5. 「_testcapi」で検索。
6. 候補は「python38-debuginfo」「python38-test」だが内容から後者と判断。
7. インストール。
8. pytestがエラーで止まらずに最後まで実施されたことを確認。

※4が決め手といえば決め手なんですが、対象範囲を絞れたからこそなので…